# How to capitalize first letter when using i18next

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

Let's say that I've `<%= _t("color") %>`

color maps to "color", so without a capital first letter

How can i make it such that it capitalizes the first letter, I don't find any option for it.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a javascript question. Are you using a template preprocessor perhaps? ruby(erb, haml, slim)? nodejs(jade, handlebars)?

Comment: default underscore templating engine (it is, because i'm using backbone.js/javascript) and I would like to have a javascript solution in case it is not supported

Comment: the [underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/) suggest a mixin for capitalization. Once you have that you can just do `_t("color").capitalize()`

Comment: Thanks the comment worked :)